# Update query string value in url

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am using following function to navigate to same page but with different query string value, page is refreshed but value in query string is not getting updated.
`SP.Utilities.HttpUtility.navigateTo(query)`;

Answer (score 1):

Can you just use `window.location`?

```
window.location.href = myNewURL;
```